# IIS 8.5 Failed Request Tracing only triggers if request duration is within 1 second of threshold

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I am only getting requests logged that take in between 1 second and 2 seconds..I expect that all requests greater than 1 second would be logged.

Here is the configuration in applicationHost.config

```
        <traceFailedRequests>
            <add path="*">
                <traceAreas>
                    <add provider="ASP" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="ASPNET" areas="Infrastructure,Module,Page,AppServices" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="ISAPI Extension" verbosity="Verbose" />
                    <add provider="WWW Server" areas="Authentication,Security,Filter,StaticFile,CGI,Compression,Cache,RequestNotifications,Module,FastCGI,WebSocket" verbosity="Verbose" />
                </traceAreas>
                <failureDefinitions timeTaken="00:00:01" />
            </add>
        </traceFailedRequests>
```

IS version 8.5.9600.16384

[Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/tracing/tracefailedrequests/add/failuredefinitions) say about timeTaken

> Optional timeSpan attribute.
>
> Specifies the maximum time that a request may spend in processing
>   before it is marked as failed and then traced.
>
> The default value is 00:00:00.

Comment: (Probably a silly question.... but.) Have you checked your IIS access logs - are there requests with an `sc-status` of greater then 399 and a `time-taken` greater than 2000? (because this behaviour sounds odd, just covering the bases) Also, could the settings be getting modified from an application level web.config or even a web.config located within a sub-folder of your site?

Comment: thanks for the tips. yes. there are requests with ``time-taken`` greater > 2000.. the status is less than 399 but that's irrelevant (IMO) because my failure definition is simply a time threshold. I double checked and the settings are not getting modified by application level web config

Comment: I would consider codes below 400 to be successful? Have you tried setting the specific http response codes your interested? Eg `statusCodes="200,301,304,307"` Also are you using extensionless urls?